# Text input Edit text Set Error handling Device rotation

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-textinputedittext

am setting Error on an edit text for validation.
However, if device is rotated then the existing style goes off and new style appears in edit text.

Is it something I need to do in OnSavedstate method or is there any work around for this..!

Comment: u need to handle rotation state inside your activity and apply same behaviour there when it is landscape..

Comment: how u set style and where ?

Comment: In code behind by setting background resource pointing to shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it myself here is what i have done. 
Decorate Activity with

```
ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | 
Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
```

This can prevent an Activity from being restarted when the orientation changes by setting ConfigurationChanges in the ActivityAttribute